token 2022 pool not showed in the blockchain
I created a 2022 token.
I then created an AMM pool on radyum which and on fluxbeam which is fully supported 2022.
both do not appear to be pools in the blockchain (solscan and solana-fm)
if I look at solana-fm it says that the pool does not exist (?)
